yum and dnf incompatible for listing all history transactions
I've noticed that yum history info "*" and dnf history info "*" are different.
yum shows the complete transactions themselves. But I don't know how to do this in dnf as it errors with No transaction which manipulates package '*' was found.. And on RHEL8 "yum" doesn't really mean yum it's still dnf code.
Is there a way to list all full text of all the transactions with dnf?

dnf history ?

dnf's interface is such that it shows the list of all transactions when you just run dnf history.

I've edited my question because you are answering in a way that with my previous wording is very reasonable. But not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a searchable format to figure out which transactions installed with packages and I need to the complete transaction text for all transactions.

dnf history | grep yourpackagenameofinteres ?
